# Can you disable Rules Components?

Tags: rules, commerce

Is there a way to disable a Rules Component? And if so, -how-?

Using Commerce, I've set up various Sales Taxes. If I understand, the Rule for Sales Tax triggers all 'Components' to be evaluated which are of type Sales Tax and then executes any/all that match the condition.

But in our case, we -know- ahead of time, that some of those Components will never be executed, so I was hoping for a way to prevent them from being evaluated and thus speed execution.

I'd prefer to keep some Components 'disabled' rather than delete them in case we need them in the future or for importing old orders.

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable Components.

- Components are configurations, so they already have an 'active' field available.
- Actions would be more difficult to disable.

You may read read from here [Components: enable / disable](https://www.drupal.org/node/871616)